# Excel Development through .Net losing Macros

Tags: .net, excel

Good Afternoon,

I have a an Excel template file - which contains Macros - that I load up in .Net. The excel document is built up on a case by case basis (the same format, but with different data dependent on what the user picks). When the Excel document is loaded up, the Macros have disappeared, does anyone know why and how to resolve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: where and how do you upload the excel document?

Comment: HI @Raj, i dont upload it as such (someone edited my text and changed it to say uploaded). I use Dim myWorkBook as Excel.Workbook = _xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\MyTemplateFile.xlsx"). The template file contains the Macros, but when i show the new Excel doc (_xlApp.Visible = True), they have disspeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using MS Office 2007 you need to take in consideration that Excel Workbook (*.xlsx) do not support macros.

You'll need to save it as Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm).

Comment: Thanks @Joao Angelo, I saved the template document as an .xlsm file and it worked perfectly.